# OOP - Python - How to call function within class and avoid the error of missing arguments caused by self?

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

I am the beginner to the OOP practices.

I want to create a `class` which execute my query to database.

Here is my code:

```
class tools():
    def connect_db(self):
        cfg = ConfigParser()
        cfg.read('env.ini')
        sv_info = cfg['sv_info']

        db =  psycopg2.connect(
            host = db_connect['host'],
            user = db_connect['user'],
            password = db_connect['password'],
            database = db_connect['database'],
            port = db_connect['port']
        )
        return db


    def run_query(self, query):
        connection = self.connect_db
        do_the_query = connection.cursor()
        do_the_query.execute(query)
        do_the_query.fetchall()
        return do_the_query

    def find_locations(self,simple_query, latitude, longitude):
        return self.run_query(simple_query).format(latitude = latitude, longitude = longitude))
```

simple_query:

```
simple_query = """select * from a_function('{latitude}' , '{lontitude}')"""
```

My code to run it:

```
tools.find_locations(simple_query , '12.123456', '21.654321')
```

However, I keep receiving the error of:

> TypeError: find_locations() missing 1 required positional argument:
> 'longitude'

According to my research, the argument `self` should not be taken to account (being ignored).

Anyway, would be nice if you guys can correct my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Note 1

I think the main issue is that you do not yet understand the difference between a "***class***" and an "***instance of a class***"

## Note 2 - What is a class?

A "***class***" represents a complex thing, such as a human person.

The "***member variables***" of a class record short simple facts about the more complicated "***class***"

A ***first name*** is an example of a good member variable for a `JobApplicant` class.

Other examples of member variables for a `JobApplicant` are as follows:

- a job-applicant's last name
- an job-applicant's age
- an applicant's phone number
- a job applicant's email address.
- etc...

A class is like a fill-in-the-blank sheet which records small facts.

Suppose that someone is writing code for a website where people buy and sell houses.

That programmer might write a class named `House` which stores statistics about a house for sale:

```
class House:
    * number of bedrooms 
    * number of bathrooms
    * square footage of the house    
    * asking price to buy the house     
    * mailing address/location of the house
    * etc...
```

A class's ***member variables*** are usually things (not actions), such as:

- mass
- velocity
- color
- temperature

class "***methods***" are functions for manipulating the member variables. ***methods*** are actions, such as:

- change_first_name
- change_phone_number
- delete
- insert
- rotate
- reflect
- translate
- enlargen
- shrink
- swim (the verb, not the noun)
- run (verb)
- eat
- skip

## NOTE 3 WHAT IS THE DIFFERENT BETWEEN A "CLASS" AND AN "INSTANCE"?

Below are some vocabulary words:

- ***instance of a class***
- ***class object***
- ***object***

All of the above terms mean the same thing.

| EXAMPLE | CLASS | INSTANCE | NOTES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `JobApplicant` class | A `JobApplicant` ***class*** is like a paper job-application form which has not been filled-out yet. The `JobApplicant` class says that every `JobApplicant` has a "first name." Tthere is a blank line for a `JobApplicant`'s pfirst name, but it has ***NOT*** been filled in yet. A ***class*** usually does **NOT** specify what a person's first name actually is. | An ***instance of a class*** is like a job application will all of the information filled-out. An ***instance*** of a `JobApplicant` class might say `first name = "Sarah"`. Not all ***instances*** have the same first nam e | A ***class*** specifies what is the same for all instances. All "`People`" have a first name (inside of the computer... maybe not in real-life). Different instances can have different first names (Robby, Evelyn). Although the details might different, every instances of the Person class does have a first name, phone number, etc.... |
| blue-print of a house | Architects draw blue-prints of houses. A ***class** is like a blue-print of a house. | an ***instance*** of a `House` class is like an actual house made out of wood, and cement, steel screws, etc... An instance is ***NOT*** like a blue-print or drawing. | Many different houses can all be built from the same blue-print. Many different instances all come from the same ***class*** |

### NOTE 4 - The `self` parameter in python

Below is some code which creates a ***class*** and an ***instance of the class***:

```python
class Cow:
    def moo(self, x = None, y = None, z = None):     
        print("M0o0o0o0o0o0o0oOoOoOoOoOoOoOoooooooooo...")
# end of Cow class

# the line below creates a new Cow named `robby`
robby = Cow()
```

- `Rectangle` is a ***class***
- `robby` is an "***instance*** of `Cow`
  ***instance*** is also known as an ***object***

The following two lines of code are equivalent to each-other:

```python
x = robby.moo(1, 2, 3)
x = Cow.moo(robby, 1, 2, 3)
```

The `self` parameter in python is automatically filled-in for you if you call a method from an ***instance*** of the class.

The `self` parameter in python is *** NOT*** automatically filled-in for you if you call a method from the ***class*** itself.

Instances and classes are different from each-other.

`self` is supposed to be an instance of the `Cow` class.

Ideally, python would complain anything you input something to the `self` parameter of the `Cow.moo` which is ***not*** a Cow.

However, python allows strange things. The python interpreter allows you to pass a Dog, Cat, or anyother animal, into the `self` paramter of `Cow.moo`

```python
class Cow:
    def moo(self, x = None, y = None, z = None):
        print(type(self))
# end of Cow class

class Dog:
    pass

class Cat:
    pass

robby = Cow()
fido = Dog()
abby_the_alley_cat = Cat()

Cow.moo(robby)
Cow.moo(fido)
Cow.moo(abby_the_alley_cat)
Cow.moo(3.1459)
Cow.moo("WHERE ART THOU ROMEO? WHERE ARE YOU MY DEAR?")
```

The console-output looks something like this:

```
<class '__main__.Cow'>
<class '__main__.Dog'>
<class '__main__.Cat'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'str'>
```

I think that you are trying to write what is known as a "***singleton class***"

If you want methods without a `self` parameter, I recommend using Google to search for something like "beginner's explanation of python ***static methods***"
You can also do some research on "python ***class methods***"

## Note [last_note_number + 1]

Below is some additional code for you to play with:

```python
import io

class BLAH(Exception):
    pass

class Cow:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # `__init__` get called every single time
        # that a new cow is instantiated from the Cow class
        #
        # Every time that a new cow comes into existence
        # the `__init__()` method is used
        #
        # I have written this function (__init__)
        # to ignore most of its input arguments.
        #
        # I recommend that you focus more on
        # understanding the difference between a class
        # and an instance of the class
        pass

    def moo(*args, **kwargs):
        # NOTE THAT:
        #     self ==args[0]
        #
        # EXAMPLE :
        #    CODE OUTSIDE OF CLASS:
        #        a = sally.moo(1, "blah", 3)
        #    INSIDE OF CLASS:
        #        args[0] == sally
        #        args[1] == 1
        #        args[2] == "blah"
        #        args[3] == 3
        output = ""
        try:
            args[0].my_static_method(*args, **kwargs)
            return output
        except AttributeError as exc:
            # `self` parameter is probably not
            # an instance of the Cow class.
            return str(exc)

    @staticmethod
    def my_static_method(*args, **kwargs):
        # The following code is confusing to read, but
        # focus more on the following two things:
        #
        #    * focus on the in-code comments describing
        #      what code does
        #
        #    * focus on what happens when you use/run the code
        #
        # The following code constructs a string.
        # The string contains the function inputs
        # We put each function-input on a different line
        #
        lamby = lambda arg: str(type(arg)).ljust(20) + repr(str(arg))
        middle = "\n".join(map(lamby, args))
        beginy = "WE ARE INSIDE OF " + "moo"
        endy = "WE ARE LEAVING " + "moo"
        output = io.StringIO()
        print(
            beginy,
            middle,
            endy,
            sep="\n",
            file=output
        )
        return output.getvalue()


    @classmethod
    def my_class_method(*args, **kwargs):
        out = ""
        try:
            out = args[0].my_static_method(*args, **kwargs)
            return out
        except BLAH:
            pass


robby = Cow(width=3, length=11)

# * `Cow` is a class
# * `robby` is an "***instance of the class***"
# `robby` is also known as an class ***object***
# instances and classes are different from each-other.

robby.moo(1, 2, 3)
Cow.moo(robby, 1, 2, 3)

simple_query = """select * from a_function('{latitude}' , '{lontitude}')"""
result = Cow.moo(simple_query , 12.123456, 21.654321)
print(result)

result = robby.moo(simple_query , 12.123456, 21.654321)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Start by defining the object with the Class. For example, we create an Object name "my_tools" with the tools() class.

```
my_tools = tools()
```

Once the object is created, then we can call the method within the class.

```
my_tools.find_locations(simple_query , '12.123456', '21.654321')
```